# Access files on Docker in javacode

Tags: docker

If it is possible, I want to have a file on my docker, which will be accesed and changed from inside a container.

I have a docker server and I am saving a person file on it, I have it saved on home/docker-user/ipps/values/person.json.

Then I have created a container in which I am running my java code. This code now should access the file I mentioned above, but there is always an error, "that the file can't be found, because it doesn't exist".

I am calling the file in a Controller with GetMapping, and saving it with PostMapping.

I changed the code locally to

```
ResourceReader.readFileToString("static/json/person.json") for GetMapping
```

and to

```
try (final FileWriter file = new FileWriter("target/classes/static/json/person.json")) {
            file.write(finalJson);
            file.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

so it overwrites the excisting file. This is working fine locally, but if I push it to the docker, there is only the Get call working.

Comment: Looks like you need a bind mount: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: I mounted it with 
docker run -t -d -p 8090:8080 -v /home/docker-user/ipps/values:/var/lib/values --name ipps-app-container ipps-app:latest

How do I need to change the Get/PostMappings to access the mounted files.

I thought, that I have to to change the ResourceReader.readFileToString("/var/lib/values/person.json") for GetMapping, but then it can't find the json

Comment: I would have guessed that too. Try to look with docker exec into the container if the mounted file is there.

Comment: It worked, I have the directory in my docker container now, I just can't access it at the moment, but I will find out why

Comment: I still can't access the data saved in the directory. I directly mounted the volume in the Jenkinsfile with  -v $JENKINS_USER_HOME/ipps/values:/values. 

And I already tried a lot of possible paths in the controller to access the data, but it always can't find the json.

I tried:
person.json
/person.json
/values/dir/person.json
/dir/person.json
/home/docker-user/ipps/values/dir/person.json

And none of them are working. If I try to manipulate the data via  insomnia/postman , i get a 200 ok response back, but nothing changed